# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in social-engine back end

Tags: javascript, jquery, socialengine

[image]I have moved my socialengine site from a hosting to a dedicated server but some functions are not working here and when i open console error log it giving me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"
but the code where it pointing the error is looks fine to me.

i am attaching a screenshot please help me.

```
function addEventForButtonAddTo() 
    {
        jQuery('button.ynvideo_add_button').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) 
        {
            e.stopPropagation();
            // remove the add to frame if it is existed on the document
            jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list').remove();

            var videoId = jQuery(this).attr('video-id');
            var btnOffset = jQuery(this).parent().offset();
            var bodyElement = jQuery('body')[0];
            var addToContextMenu =  jQuery(bodyElement)
                .append('<div id="ynvideo_addTo_menu_list"><div class="ynvideo_addTo_frame" id="ynvideo_addTo_frame_loading"><div id="ynvideo_addTo_loading"><?php echo $this->translate('LOADING')?></div></div></div>');
            jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list').css({
                        'left' : btnOffset.left,
                        'top' : btnOffset.top + jQuery(this).outerHeight()
                    });  

            jQuery.get(
                '<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'add-to'), 'video_general', true) ?>', 
                {'video_id' : videoId},
                function(data) {                    
                    var addToContextMenu = jQuery(data).insertAfter('#ynvideo_addTo_frame_loading');                

                    jQuery(document).bind('click', function(event) {
                        var target = event.target;
                        // if the user click outside the add to menu box, remove the add to menu box
                        if (jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list').has(event.target).length == 0) {
                            jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list').remove();
                            jQuery(document).unbind('click');
                        }
                    });

                    jQuery('#ynvideo_menu_item_add_to_new_playlist').click(function() {
                        nextSlideNewPlaylist();    
                    });

                        jQuery('#ynvideo_menu_item_cancel').click(function() {
                             jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list > div').hide();
                        });
                        jQuery('#ynvideo_menu_item_cancel_successfully').click(function() {
                             jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list > div').hide();
                        });
                        jQuery('#ynvideo_menu_item_cancel_dupplicate').click(function() {
                             jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list > div').hide();
                        });
                        jQuery('#ynvideo_menu_item_cancel_unsuccessfully').click(function() {
                             jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_menu_list > div').hide();
                        });


                    jQuery('#ynvideo_quick_create_playlist').submit(function() {                       
                        var params = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
                        var action = jQuery(this).attr('action');
                        nextSlideLoading();
                        jQuery.post(action, params, function(data) {
                            afterAddedToPlaylist(data);
                            return false;    
                        });
                        return false;
                    });

                    jQuery('#ynvideo_add_to_watch_later').click(function() {                    
                        nextSlideLoading();
                        jQuery.post(
                            '<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'add-to'), 'video_watch_later') ?>', 
                            {'video_id' : videoId},
                            afterAddedToPlaylist
                        );            

                    });

                    jQuery('#ynvideo_addTo_list .ynvideo_menu_item_playlist').click(function() {
                        nextSlideLoading();
                        var playlistId = jQuery(this).attr('playlist');
                        jQuery.post(
                            '<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'add'), 'video_playlist') ?>', 
                            {'playlist_id' : playlistId, 'video_id' : videoId},
                            afterAddedToPlaylist
                        );
                    });

                    jQuery('.ynvideo_add_to_favorite_menu_item').click(function() {
                        nextSlideLoading();
                        jQuery.post(
                            '<?php echo $this->url(array('action' => 'add'), 'video_favorite')?>',
                            {'video_id' : videoId},
                            afterAddedToPlaylist
                        );
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }
```

Comment: You have mismatched quotes `<?php echo $this->translate('LOADING')?>`.

Comment: Why did you tag MooTools in this question?

Comment: i have changed this to <?php echo $this->translate("Loading")?> but still having issue on same location.

Comment: as socialengine having mootools in its core and one or more plugins using jquery.

Comment: since this is hard to reproduce, I can only guess. Try:
1) switching `bodyElement` to just `'body'`
2) extracting the divs you're appending to a variable, and `console.log` or debugging it to ensure its a valid element.
3) providing more info, such as what the end result looks like, and what value of `bodyElement` is in the console